# How to copy files that are very large

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

I would like to copy files which are nearly 50GB and 75GB of each to external drive. Please suggest best and fastest way to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? What's wrong with `cp file /path/to/drive`?

Comment: I want to copy it to external hard drive.

Comment: @IsmailShaik Mount the external hard drive and do `cp file path/that/you/mounted/to`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your external drive is plugged to your computer.
If it is some NAS, so you are connected through some network and you may loss the connection, I suggest you to use rsync with the option "--partial" so you can continue the transfer by issuing the same command if it get interrupted.

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more please. I would like to copy data to my external hard drive. Actually i have nearly 3 TB of data needs to be copied in the same manner. One of my question is how to copy data in linux box to external hard drive.

Comment: Well assuming you have a local directory "to_save/" that you would like to copy to a disk that is mounted on /mnt you will issue a command like: "rsync -r --partial to_save/ /mnt" . I usually use rsync when I have to copy files through some network (ftp, ssh...), rsync automatically detect files that are already copied to you destination, and in case of big files, if you lose the connection during a file transfers, the "--partial" option will allow you to resume your copy saving you some times.

Comment: If your external hard drive is connected through a robust connection (usb connection is quite stable on all major Linux distributions nowadays) a basic "cp" will do the job... as I said, rsync is useful when your connection between your linux host and your external hard drive could be unexpectedly interrupted.

Comment: @IsmailShaik If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.